# Wrong subscription pop up with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-storyboard

Problem: I'm trying to get the subscription page coded in Xcode so that when someone wants to buy a subscription it shows the subscription pop up at the bottom with the button subscribe

What's happening in real life: I created a button to click so a subscription pop can come up but the pop up doesn't look the same   it says at the top: "Sign In with Apple ID" and there's 2 text fields at the bottom asking for the Apple ID and password but I want the usual pop up that shows PRICE       2.99/WEEK and the details of the subscription.

What I did: I looked for videos online and saw one that uses Qonversion for subscriptions and I followed the code but I'm not getting the subscription pop up like in the video I'm getting another pop up visual and I want the pop up that shows the details and price with the word "Subscribe" at the bottom.[desired subscription image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pucg.jpg)

reality: [the subscription pop up I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3j63.png)

the video I followed : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U34fsZJ3YA8

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot/code of your issue? It helps us help you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and include a [mre]

Comment: Ok I added an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between desired image and reality is that your device is not yet connected with a (Sandbox) Apple ID.

Sign in once with your (Sandbox) Apple ID. Then you will see the desired subscription popup.

Comment: Wow you solved it. I was watching videos and all and I even been trying to get subscriptions into my app for about a month. I didn't know that was all I had to do. Thanks!